# Auto slider manual controls not applying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add manual control to an auto slider: https://jsfiddle.net/t8ap0gvz/ The auto play works but the manual controls (prev/next & dots) don't function. What am I doing wrong?

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

showSlides();

function showSlides() {    
var i;    
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}

function currentSlide(no) {
var i;    
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
slideIndex = no;
slides[no-1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(n) {
var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
if(newslideIndex < 4 && newslideIndex > 0){
 currentSlide(newslideIndex);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the answer above,he said about the DOM to load, in JSfiddle in the option of the javascript change the order in where the javascript is write. For functions in onclick is better put after all the html, by default JSfiddle put in windows.onload so only change the order in No wrap - bottom of  and this will work.

[In LOAD TYPE select that option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98gQi.png)

In a real code HTML the script tag will be in the end of your HTML body. In a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's loading the functions before the html. When I move the call of showSlides()  to like below it works:

```
// Await DOM to be loaded
if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    showSlides();
  });
} else {
  showSlides();
}
```